# Polymer document.querySelector not working as expected

Tags: polymer

Either I am doing something horribly wrong or Polymer just doesn't like me. See following:

```
<polymer-element name="menu-paper-ui" noscript>
 <template>
  <paper-dialog heading="Dialog" transition="paper-dialog-transition-bottom">
  [ .. ]
  </paper-dialog>
  <paper-button label="Dialog Bottom" on-tap="{{toggleDialog}}"></paper-button>

 </template>
 <script>
  Polymer('menu-paper-ui', { 
    toggleDialog : function() {
      var dialog = document.querySelector('paper-dialog');
      console.log(dialog); //returns null
      dialog.toggle();
    }
  })

 </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Now, I have my reasons to use  `querySelector`. So, if someone can tell me whats going wrong that will be great!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Polymer element querySelector is null for nested elements in template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24627076/polymer-element-queryselector-is-null-for-nested-elements-in-template)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This question is nearly identical to [Using querySelector to find nested elements inside a Polymer template returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24627076/3303267).

The short answer is that elements in a polymer-element's template are put into the ShadowDOM of that element, are not not visible to the anything outside of that element. This is so that you can control styling more easily, and element IDs are scoped.

You can either give the dialog an id and use Polymer's automatic node finding, or use `this.shadowRoot.querySelector('paper-dialog')`.

Answer (score 2):

The Problem is that you can not access the shadow DOM inside a custom element with `document.querySelector`. [See my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24627076/polymer-element-queryselector-is-null-for-nested-elements-in-template/24629922#24629922).