# How to add multiple polymer elements in HTML

Tags: html, polymer

I am new to polymer designing. Currently I have 4 html pages with polymer elements and 1 html file where all the 4 polymer elements are imported.

In the child html (polymer object) when I try to access controls (paper-button) using document.querySelector, it says null.

Can anybody please explain how can i access the imported elements in the parent page and add events to the buttons in the child polymer.

Thanks in advance

Regards
Darshan

Comment: Please add some code that shows what you've done so far and what you want to achieve. And the title of your question doesn't match your problem description because it seems that you already successfully added multiple polymer elements to your main page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using querySelector to find nested elements inside a Polymer template returns null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24627076/using-queryselector-to-find-nested-elements-inside-a-polymer-template-returns-nu/24629922#24629922)