# Traversing into Local DOM from Outside of the Component Using JavaScript

Tags: polymer, shady-dom

I am trying to access the local DOM elements from outside of the Polymer components using JavaScript. In the past I could use the `document.querySelector` and select the shadowDOM elements using the `::shadow` selector.

Currently, I understand that the local DOM is implemented as "shady DOM". How do I access the local DOM elements in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have a component like the one below, and you need to get to the `div` element from outside of the component:

```
<dom-module id="my-element">
  <template>
    <div id="container"></div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({is: 'my-element'});
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

And on your page, you place the element as:

```
<my-element id="myElement"></my-element>
```

The first thing we do is get a reference to the `custom-element` element in our page JS:

```
var myElement = document.getElementById('myElement');
```

Now, to get to the `div` we have two options.  The first one is Polymer's handy [automatic node finding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom.html#node-finding).  This makes it so that every element in your component (that exists and is stamped prior to `ready`) is added to `this.$.<my-id>`.  That makes it easy to reach from the outside, like so:

```
var div = myElement.$.container;
```

But if the `div` does not have an ID, or is otherwise unreachable like this, you can use Polymer's own `querySelector` attached to the element itself, like so:

```
var div = myElement.querySelector('div');
```

I have to say, though, that both of these should really be "last resort" methods for interacting with a component.  Often rather than exposing a DOM element directly, you should instead expose a method or property that drives that component's DOM.  I recommend you drop by the [Polymer Slack](https://polymer.slack.com) chat and let us know what you're looking to do, and we can give you some good options.

Comment: hi Zikes. Thanks for the solution. I have issue joining the Polymer Slack, it seems like i need to be invited.

Answer (score 0):

This was not enough in my case. What helped me in the end was the answer above, combined with this:
[shadowRoot.querySelector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26822859/6213524)

```
var myElement = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#myElement');
var div = myElement.shadowRoot.querySelector('div');
```

I have to add that i am a beginner when it comes to polymer so I cant really explain why this worked for me and not the code above.
But I believe this was the case because I used myElement inside a page which is in the end a custom element by itself.