# Accessing a div inside of a Polymer element template

Tags: javascript, selector, polymer, shadow-dom

I'm trying to use core-animation on a div, to animate its position. To do that, i have to select it with document.getElementById().
The problem is, i have a rather complex structure in my index.html file and i can't find a way to select that div.

Here's index.html structure (i need to select #el): https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdeO3.jpg

My index.html file:

```
    <template is="auto-binding" id="t">

  <!-- Route controller. -->
  <flatiron-director route="{{route}}" autoHash></flatiron-director>

  <!-- Keyboard nav controller. -->
  <core-a11y-keys id="keys" target="{{parentElement}}"
                  keys="up down left right space space+shift"
                  on-keys-pressed="{{keyHandler}}"></core-a11y-keys>
<core-header-panel>
<core-toolbar  class="panel-personal" hidden?="{{shortView}}">
...
</core-toolbar>
  <core-toolbar class="panel-nav">
    <paper-tabs valueattr="hash" selected="{{route}}" selectedModel="{{selectedPage}}"
                 on-core-select="{{menuItemSelected}}" link flex style="width:100%; height:100%;" id="tabs">
      <template repeat="{{page, i in pages}}">
          <paper-tab><a href="#{{page.hash}}">{{page.date_month}}<br/><small>{{page.date_year}}</small></a></paper-tab>
      </template>
    </paper-tabs>
</core-toolbar>
          <nav class="menu">
...
      </nav>


    <div horizontal layout fit>

      <core-animated-pages id="pages" selected="{{route}}" valueattr="hash"
                           transitions="slide-from-right"
                           on-tap="{{cyclePages}}" flex self-stretch>
        <template repeat="{{page, i in pages}}">
          <section hash="{{page.hash}}" class="card-wrapper">
            <div flex fit>
              <div class="card-container" vertical layout fit >
                <h1>{{page.name}}</h1>
                <h2>{{page.category}}</h2>
                <paper-button raised class="project_button"><a href="{{page.link}}" target="_blank"><core-icon icon="social:share" ></core-icon> visit project</a> </paper-button>
              </div>
              <div center-justified layout fit class="card-content">
                <div>
                  <h4>Project description</h4>
                  <p>{{page.desc}}
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card-background" id="el" fit></div>
            </div>
           </section>
        </template>
      </core-animated-pages>
    </div>

</core-header-panel>
</template>
```

How can i select that #el div?

Comment: Which `el`? Your `<div class="card-background" id="el" fit></div>` is inside a `<template repeat="{{page, i in pages}}">` so there's going to potentially be multiple `div#el` stamped out to the DOM.

Comment: Right. I realized that it does produce 5 divs with an id="el" so giving that div an id doesnt work. What I'm essentially trying to do is animate that div.card-background on a page that is currently selected. When a page is selected, it has "active" as a parameter and a class "core-selected". I need to launch play() function for the active page div, but I need to target it first and I don't know how to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your element is inside a template, then it does not belong to the DOM but the *[shadow DOM](https://www.w3.org/TR/shadow-dom/)*. As a complement, in the Web Components site there is [an article on the topic](http://webcomponents.org/articles/introduction-to-shadow-dom/) and Rob Dodson wrote [a detailed article about the basics of *shadow DOM*](http://robdodson.me/shadow-dom-the-basics/).

**Edit** : Polymer 1.0 introduced a specific concept, [Shady DOM](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/blog/shadydom)...

I admit the relationship between a polymer element, multiple templates and *shadow DOM* is not really obvious to me. At first glance, a *shadow DOM* is associated to a template. A few explanations are available in [that other article by Rob Dodson about templates repetition](http://robdodson.me/repeating-templates-in-polymer/). It seems with repetitions things become subtle: here you have a single *shadow DOM* and the ID becomes pointless. The worse is that I guess you have nested *shadow DOM*s because of the nested templates. What is not clear at all to me is here: what about visibility in such a context ?

**Edit** : more informations about visibility are available in [that later exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28704634/1207019)...

**Edit** : template repetition syntax [has evolved in *Polymer 1.0*](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates#dom-repeat)

As a conclusion (in my understanding), **because of the template repetition** you could have multiple identical IDs even inside the repeated template *shadow DOM*. The valid strategy would be to **use a class for selection instead of an ID**.

*Javascript* is [associated to a *Polymer* element with a method call](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/quick-tour). To select via *Javascript* in the *shadow DOM*, you should use the *querySelector*. The solution you suggested with *document.getElementById()* is valid for the DOM. The point is about nested templates. You have a hint with [another exchange on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24629922). A solution is suggested with *this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll(...)* but an [issue in the *Polymer* project](https://github.com/Polymer/docs/issues/477) covers the point: this could work but probably not a good practice. The details in the *Polymer* documentation about node finding are [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom#node-finding): in that article there is a sample looking like your problem.

According to the *Polymer* doc, when you call the *Polymer* element method, assuming you want the selection in the *ready* event and a *container* ID assigned in your nesting template, this should look something like this:

```
<polymer-element name="my-element"...>
  <template ...>
    <div id="container">
      <template ...>
        ...
        <div class="el">
        </div>
        ...
      </template>
    </div>
  </template>
  <script>
Polymer('my-element', {
  ready: function() {
    this.$.container.querySelector('.el');
  }
});
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```