# Polymer data-binding: how to access data in nested template?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, web-component

I want to implement a page containing a paper-tabs, with each tab showing a list of items according to the name initial. I wonder what is the best way for data-binding.

Also I have some trouble to access the data in the nested template. When I tap different tabs, it is not working as I expect.

Here is the simplified code:

```
//page
<paper-tabs selected="{{tab}}">
  <template repeat="{{inital in pagination}}">
    <paper-tab name="{{initial}}">
      {{initial}}
    </paper-tab>
  </template>
</paper-tabs>

<items-field
  tab="{{tab}}"
  items="{{items}}">
</items-field>


//items-field
<polymer-element name="items-field" attributes="tab items">
  <template>
    <h2>h2 {{tab}}</h2>
    <div>some other stuffs</div>
    <template bind="{{items}}">
      <h3>h3 {{tab}}</h3> <-- {{tab}} is undefined
      <item-list
        initial="{{tab}}"
      </item-list>
    </template>
  </template>
  <script>
  Polymer({
    tab: 'A'
  )}
  </script>
</polymer-element>


//item-list
<polymer-element name="items-list" attributes="initial">
  <template>
    <template repeat="{{item in items}}">
      <item
        hidden?="{{toHide(initial, item.name)}}">
      </item>
    </template>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      ready: function () {
        this.items = this.templateInstance.model;
        console.log(this.initial); // <-- undefined
      },

      toHide: function (initial, name) {
        if (initial === undefined ||
          initial === name.charAt(0)) {
          return false;
        }

        return true;
      }
    });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the main issue you're running into is messing up your binding scopes.

This bit here:

```
<template bind="{{items}}">
  <h3>h3 {{tab}}</h3> <-- {{tab}} is undefined
  <item-list initial="{{tab}}"
  </item-list>
</template>
```

By binding to `items`, you've created a new scope specific to the `items` object. So looking for `{{tab}}` within that scope, is like asking for `items.tab` which is not what you want. You can jump back to the parent scope in certain situations using named scopes, but not in this case. [Explained more here](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/expressions.html#expression-scopes). (Also, your code says item-list when it should be item**s**-list).

So I solved this in a different way by omitting the bind to items and just passing the items collection down to the children.

```
<template is="auto-binding" id="app">

  <paper-tabs selected="{{tab}}" valueattr="name">
    <template repeat="{{initial in pagination}}">
      <paper-tab name="{{initial}}">
        {{initial}}
      </paper-tab>
    </template>
  </paper-tabs>

  <items-field tab="{{tab}}"
               items="{{items}}">
  </items-field>

</template>

<script>
  var app = document.querySelector('#app');
  app.pagination = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
  app.tab = 'B';
  app.items = [{name: 'Alpha'}, {name: 'Beta'}, {name: 'Charlie'}];
</script>

<polymer-element name="items-field" attributes="tab items">
  <template>
    <h2>h2 {{t}}</h2>
    <div>some other stuffs</div>
    <h3>h3 {{tab}}</h3>
    <items-list initial="{{tab}}" items="{{items}}"></items-list>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      tab: 'A'
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>

<polymer-element name="items-list" attributes="initial items">
  <template>
    <div>{{initial}}</div>
    <template repeat="{{item in items}}">
      <div hidden?="{{toHide(initial, item.name)}}">
        {{item.name}}
      </div>
    </template>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({

      ready: function () {

      },

      toHide: function (initial, name) {
        if (initial === undefined ||
            initial === name.charAt(0)) {
          return false;
        }

        return true;
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

[JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/joruza/13/edit)

Comment: Thanks @robdodson! I like the idea of "element is the model". My understanding: when I use "bind", that element is that model; when I use "attribute", I inject something into the model. What is the best practice, use "bind" or use "attribute"?

Comment: bind is primarily for creating a template scope and, as I see it, just saves on typing. I would try to make as many of your components stateless and dumb as possible. Then flow data to them through attribute bindings.