# Internal Links in Polymer 2.0

Tags: polymer, shadow-dom, polymer-2.x

What is the correct way to implement internal linking in Polymer 2.0 (linking within the same page)? I cannot seem to get access to my components that are buried within ShadowDoms, so the traditional way of using `<a href="#my_section">link to top</a>` and `<a name="my_section"></a>` and `<a id="my_section"></a>` does not work.

I have also tried the solutions here to no avail:

- [How to query elements within shadow DOM from outside in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29629492/how-to-query-elements-within-shadow-dom-from-outside-in-dart)
- [Is it possible to access Shadow DOM elements through the parent document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633057/is-it-possible-to-access-shadow-dom-elements-through-the-parent-document)
- [Using querySelector to find nested elements inside a Polymer template returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24627076/using-queryselector-to-find-nested-elements-inside-a-polymer-template-returns-nu)

The following code that I've tried all return null, even when I add an id to my component:

```
document.querySelector('#my_section'); //null
this.$.my_section; //null
this.root.querySelector('#my_section'); //null
this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#my_section'); //null
```

Perhaps there is a way to accomplish this using `<app-route>`?

I'm quite new to Polymer so any advice would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "#my_section" queries for an `<a id="my_section">`? are u sure you want to use name?

Comment: @daKmoR I've actually tried "id" as well, but that does not work either. I've updated the question.

Comment: Are you querying from within the element, or from outside of it?

Comment: Hi @codeMonkey, I'm querying from outside the element.

Answer (score 0):

Please share more detailed code that which elements you want to access and manuplate. Here at this document

```
https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/dom-template
```

under the `Static node map` head shows shortly :

> The this.$ hash is created when the shadow DOM is initialized. In the
>   ready callback, you must call super.ready() before accessing this.$.